# How to check drawn line doesn't go outside of form area?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, line

I found a shape drawing article from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools). I am trying to add a check so that the drawn line doesn't go outside of form area.

Appreciate your guidance in resolving this.

Comment: I've fixed the form width and height to 640x480. Two approaches I tried but doesn't seem to work exactly. 1. subtract X1 from X2 and Y1 from Y2 to get the absolute width and height. Then when it is moving I check against the 640x480. If it is more than 640x480 then update it to the 640x480. In that end point doesn't go out of scope but start point keep increasing and goes out of scope. 2. Checking start point and end point for the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Contains` method of a `Rectangle`. Try this:

```
bool isLineCutOff = !(yourForm.ClientRectangle.Contains(p1) &&
                      yourForm.ClientRectangle.Contains(p2));
//p1 and p2 are 2 endpoints of your line.
```